# docker-entrypoint-initdb.d bad interpreter: Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

Hi I a using `postgres` `docker-compose` in my application. When I am trying to run it on my local machine (macOS Big Sur) I am getting below error and `postgres` container exited.

```
 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgres-ssl.sh
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgres-ssl.sh: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Below is my `docker-compose`

```
postgres:
build:
  context: ./setup/postgres
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
command:
  -c ssl=on -c ssl_cert_file=/var/lib/postgresql/ssl/certs/server.crt
  -c ssl_key_file=/var/lib/postgresql/ssl/certs/server.key
  -c ssl_ca_file=/var/lib/postgresql/ssl/certs/root.crt
ports:
  - '5432:5432'
volumes:
  - ./setup/postgres/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
environment:
  - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

Am I missing any steps here?

Answer (score 38):

I ended up running into this same issue. For anyone who faces this, you need to give execution permission to your script file, since Docker copies over permissions:

```
chmod +x your/script.sh
```

In my case the issue msg was:

```
/opt/bitnami/scripts/libpostgresql.sh: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/my-initdb.sh: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

Then I gave execution permission to `my-initdb.sh` and it worked nicely

Comment: strangely enough this does not happen in WSL 2

Comment: I've also had this problem *(on Mac OS). The above fix worked for me. For anyone not sure exactly how to do it, I opened the folder containing the script on my system in the terminal and ran `chmod +x init.sh` and it worked.

Comment: ahhhhhhh, this was my problem, give `chmod +x` permission  to any bash file to make it runnable, thanks a lot

Comment: is there any way to reduce the scope of the `chmod +x` and just add the execute permission for the specific pgsql group instead ? (for security reasons)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without creating a dockerfile? I am using the base image "gvenzl/oracle-free:slim" directly on the docker-compose file